# Count number of Mondays, Tuesdays etc from table using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of Mondays, Tuesdays etc in a table using Linq and C#

Here is my sample data:

```
Status      StatusDate

DELIVRD     2015-04-16 11:57:47.000

DELIVRD     2015-04-16 13:02:57.000
```

I know I need to use Group by to group the same Mondays, Tuesdays etc as 1.

My attempt:

```
var mondays = rad.SMSSentItems
    .Where(x => (x.StatusDate.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) 
             && (x.Status == "DELIVRD"))
    .ToList()
    .Count;
```

Comment: Didn't we already do this in SQL?

Comment: That was for the average count per day of the month for all months. Now I'm building another report which shows the average SMS's send per day of the week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter by the desired Status (`DELIVRD`) then group them by `DayOfWeek` of the status date

```
var weekDays = rad.SMSSentItems
    .Where(x => x.Status == "DELIVRD")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.StatusDate.Value.DayOfWeek)
    .Select(g => {
        //Total items sent on this day of the week
        var totalItemCount = g.Count();
        //Total number if this distinct day of the week
        var totalNumberOfDays = g.Select(x => x.StatusDate.Value.Date).Distinct().Count();
        return new {
            DayOfWeek = g.Key,
            TotalItemCount = totalItemCount,
            TotalNumberOfDays = totalNumberOfDays,
            AverageItemPerDay = totalItemCount / totalNumberOfDays
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I've tried your code and I get the following error:

The specified type member 'DayOfWeek' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @Orion see update. Linq to SQL does not know how to convert the `x.StatusDate.Value.DayOfWeek` so I short circuit the generated query by placing the `AsEnumerable()` to execute the filter on the database side then linq to entities will do the grouping on the projected objects.

Comment: I got passed the error, however the result does not seem like it's giving me the grouped days. This is the result I'm getting:

[Monday, 10323]-[Tuesday, 11031]-[Wednesday, 11079]-[Thursday, 11145]-[Friday, 9775]-[Saturday, 180]-[Sunday, 268]

Comment: @Orion I think I understand now what it is you wanted based on one of your earlier comments on the original question. Check update.

Comment: this hit the nail on the head. Exactly what was required. Thank you!